# How to get the JSONArray without variables?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Im sorry for asking such a simple question, im struggling to get the values in JSONArray in the JSONArray without the variables inside the Array. Im using Retrofit library in android studio.Give me link or hint to get the value, please help. TQ in advance.

**And here is the JSON format:**

```
 {  
   "meta":{  
      "code":200
   },
   "response":{  
      "provider":"jakim",
      "code":"wlp-0",
      "origin":"wlp-0",
      "jakim":"sgr03",
      "source":"http:\/\/www.e-solat.gov.my\/web\/muatturun.php?zone=sgr03&year=2018&bulan=7&jenis=year&lang=my&url=http:\/\/mpt.i906.my",
      "place":"Kuala Lumpur",
      "times":[  
         [  
            1531691280,
            1531696200,
            1531718520,
            1531730760,
            1531740600,
            1531745100
         ],
         [  ],
         [  ],
         [  ],
         [  ],
         [  ],
         [  ]
      ]
   }
}
```

or can view the link for json: [json link here](https://mpt.i906.my/api.html)

**Here is my code:**

```
  private void getPrayTimeMalay(String code, String filter) {
    ApiServiceInterface apiEndPoint = Utility.getRetrofitInstanceMalay().create(ApiServiceInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = apiEndPoint.getPrayerTimeMalay(code, filter);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            try {
                String tmp = response.body().string();
                JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(tmp);
                Log.d("getPrayer", "onResponse: " + jsonData);

                JSONObject jsonMeta = jsonData.getJSONObject("meta");
                JSONObject jsonResponse = jsonMeta.getJSONObject("response");

                if (jsonMeta.getInt("code") == 200) {
                    PrayerTime prayerTime = new PrayerTime();
                    prayerTime.code = jsonResponse.getString("code");
                    prayerTime.origin = jsonResponse.getString("origin");
                    prayerTime.place = jsonResponse.getString("place");

                    JSONArray jsonTime = new JSONArray("times");
                    for (int i = 0; i <= jsonTime.length(); i++) {


                    }

                }


            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any methods on the that `jsonTime` variable? What errors do you get when you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: @cricket_007 I know how to parse json in android but this one a bit tricky. How to get the jsonArray and stored it, without the json variables.

Comment: after few hint from @Navneet Krishna i found the solution and want to share with the community. Here is the way on how to retrieve the data: check the edited code.

Comment: You don't have "json variables" in an array. You only have indices. The duplicate shows that you can loop over an array. Or you can directly call `get(index)`. You can post answers below rather than in the question. Besides that, you could just use Gson to map the JSON directly to a Java object

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
JSONArray jsonTime = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("times");
```

** EDIT **

```
    try {
        String st= (String) jsonTime.get(0);
        mTextview.setText(st);  //set the first item in array to textview
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: when i get the data in "times" and stored it. How can I retrieve the data and display one data in textview.

Comment: after few hint from @Navneet Krishna i found the solution and want to share with the community. Here is the way on how to retrieve the data:  check the edited code.